# How to automate the installation and use of conda to launch a python script?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a python project that uses streamlit as its gui. Since I'm graduating from my lab I'm trying to make it as easy as possible to use, and to somewhat futureproof it by automating setup in case the lab gets a new PC or laptop. Whats the easiest way to automate for windows (either as a batch script, msi, exe, etc.)? It should:

Setup:

1. Install anaconda/miniconda
2. Install pip libraries from requirements.txt file

Use:

1. Start python through miniconda/anaconda env
2. Run `streamlit run myscript.py` via env
3. Allow script to access "input" and "output" folders to read/store files in

What I tried:

A windows.bat batch script. This works great for starting the script but still requires the user to find conda location and edit the batch file. I would like to minimize this, as some people in our lab are very technically challenged (I've had to train multiple on copy-pasting the location from explorer address).

```
@ECHO OFF

:: EDIT ME ::
:: Edit the below line to point to the anaconda directory as demonstrated below ::
CALL C:\Users\albei\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\albei\anaconda3

pip install -r requirements.txt
echo ''
echo "-------------------------------------"
echo "Starting the dynamic bike script"
echo ''
echo "Keep this window open while the script is running"
echo "-------------------------------------"

:: This line just runs the streamlit script ::
streamlit run new_bike_st.py

:: Keep the terminal open ::
PAUSE
```

Comment: Deploy the project in Docker may be a way to go.

Comment: Hm, I've only ever used Docker to deploy stuff on a local server. Is there a method to end up with "double click and launch"?

Comment: Yes and it is a nice way to hide complexity and support portability. It requires docker client installed and that the project folder is copied locally. I do not have experience with Streamlit specifically but has used docker for plotly dash apps. I found this guide that may help you: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-deploy-streamlit-app-with-docker/

Comment: So I messed around with docker a little bit, following the link you helpfully provided. I have a couple issues with it, mainly: it hides my files (there is a homepage.txt file I'd like to keep exposed so users can upgrade protocol instructions as needed) and folders (users copy files into input folder, although this can be solved by asking them to use the streamlit webgui to upload but I'm not sure if the files will forever remain in thecontainer?), and a minor issue that it doesn't automatically open the streamlit webgui. Users have to manually type in localhost:8501 in the browser.

Comment: You can use bind mounts to access files on the host computer from the docker. And yes - you propably need to manually start the browser.